# PHP MySQL Query With Distinct and LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need your advice with my PHP MySQL query using `SELECT DISTINCT`. The data result is show as I wanted. But now facing problem, the data show is not keep show 5 row. Sometimes 6 row, sometimes 4 and etc.

Please help! Is there any way to query my code below:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_post WHERE uid = '$uid' LIMIT 5");
while($d_check = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$q2 = mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT C.uid_fk, C.msg_id_fk, C.comment, C.created, U.username, U.uid, U.full_name, U.avatar
    FROM tb_comment C, tb_user U
    WHERE C.uid_fk = U.uid AND C.msg_id_fk = '$get_post_id'
    AND C.uid_fk != '$uid' ORDER BY C.created LIMIT 5");
}
```

Comment: Try to join 3 tables at once.

Comment: `the data show is not keep show` What does that mean?

Comment: Means, all data show with LIMIT no function. Sometimes data show more than 5, whereas I already LIMIT that query